# Selection of Mini-batch Size for Neural Network Regression

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent

I am doing a neural network regression with 4 features. How do I determine the size of mini-batch for my problem? I see people use 100 ~ 1000 batch size for computer vision with 32*32*3 features for each image, does that mean I should use batch size of 1 million? I have billions of data and tens of GB of memory so there is no hard requirement for me not to do that.

I also observed using a mini-batch with size ~ 1000 makes the convergence much faster than batch size of 1 million. I thought it should be the other way around, since the gradient calculated with a larger batch size is most representative of the gradient of the whole sample? Why does using mini-batch make the convergence faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164876/12359):

From Nitish Shirish Keskar, Dheevatsa Mudigere, Jorge Nocedal, Mikhail Smelyanskiy, Ping Tak Peter Tang. On Large-Batch Training for Deep Learning: Generalization Gap and Sharp Minima. https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04836 :

> The stochastic gradient descent method and its variants are algorithms of choice for many Deep Learning tasks. These methods operate in a small-batch regime wherein a fraction of the training data, usually 32--512 data points, is sampled to compute an approximation to the gradient. **It has been observed in practice that when using a larger batch there is a significant degradation in the quality of the model, as measured by its ability to generalize.** There have been some attempts to investigate the cause for this generalization drop in the large-batch regime, however the precise answer for this phenomenon is, hitherto unknown. In this paper, we present ample numerical evidence that supports the view that large-batch methods tend to converge to sharp minimizers of the training and testing functions -- and that sharp minima lead to poorer generalization. In contrast, small-batch methods consistently converge to flat minimizers, and our experiments support a commonly held view that this is due to the inherent noise in the gradient estimation. We also discuss several empirical strategies that help large-batch methods eliminate the generalization gap and conclude with a set of future research ideas and open questions.
>
> […]
>
> **The lack of generalization ability is due to the fact that large-batch methods tend to converge to *sharp minimizers* of the training function**.  These minimizers are characterized by large positive eigenvalues in $\nabla^2 f(x)$  and tend to generalize less well. In contrast, small-batch methods converge to flat minimizers characterized by small positive eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f(x)$. We have observed that the loss function landscape of deep neural networks is such that large-batch methods are almost invariably attracted to regions with sharp minima and that, unlike small batch methods, are unable to escape basins of these minimizers.
>
> […]
>
> [image]

Also, some good insights from [Ian Goodfellow](https://www.quora.com/profile/Ian-Goodfellow)
answering to [why do not use the whole training set to compute the gradient?](https://www.quora.com/Deep-learning-why-do-not-use-the-whole-training-set-to-compute-the-gradient)
 on Quora:

> The size of the learning rate is limited mostly by factors like how
>   curved the cost function is. You can think of gradient descent as
>   making a linear approximation to the cost function, then moving
>   downhill along that approximate cost. If the cost function is highly
>   non-linear (highly curved) then the approximation will not be very
>   good for very far, so only small step sizes are safe. You can read
>   more about this in Chapter 4 of the deep learning textbook, on
>   numerical computation:
>   http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html
>
> When you put
>   m examples in a minibatch, you need to do O(m) computation and use
>   O(m) memory, but you reduce the amount of uncertainty in the gradient
>   by a factor of only O(sqrt(m)). In other words, there are diminishing
>   marginal returns to putting more examples in the minibatch. You can
>   read more about this in Chapter 8 of the deep learning textbook, on
>   optimization algorithms for deep learning:
>   http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html
>
> Also, if
>   you think about it, even using the entire training set doesn’t really
>   give you the true gradient. The true gradient would be the expected
>   gradient with the expectation taken over all possible examples,
>   weighted by the data generating distribution. Using the entire
>   training set is just using a very large minibatch size, where the size
>   of your minibatch is limited by the amount you spend on data
>   collection, rather than the amount you spend on computation.