# How dose the setting of steps_per_epoch and epochs affect the training result in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, epoch, unsupervised-learning, adam

My generator always yields two images from my dataset randomly and then I calculate the loss using this two samples. Say I set `steps_per_epoch=40` and  `epochs=5`, what's the difference if I set `steps_per_epoch=5` and `epochs=40` (I use Adam for my optimizer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `epochs` argument (also called iteration) refers to the number of full passes over the whole training data. The `steps_per_epoch` argument refers to the number of batches generated during one epoch. Therefore we have `steps_per_epoch = n_samples / batch_size`.

For example, if we have 1000 training samples and we set batch-size to 10 then we have `steps_per_epoch = 1000 / 10 = 100`. The `epochs` can be set regardless of the value of batch-size or `steps_per_epoch`.

There is no definite value of batch-size that works for all the scenarios. Usually, a very large batch-size slows down the training process (i.e. it takes more time for the model to converge to a solution) and a very small batch-size may not be a good use of available resources (i.e. GPU and CPU). The usual values include 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 (powers of 2 helps with faster GPU memory allocations). Also, [here is an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46655895/2099607) that concerns this issue which includes citations of relevant books and papers. Or take a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/153531/114422) and its answers on Cross Validated for a more complete definition of batch-size.

Comment: But how does it affect the result? For 1000 training samples, if i set batch_size to 100 and then steps_per_epoch will be 10. Will this have a different impact on the training?

Comment: @TeresaHo I updated my post. Please take a look at it.