# Tensorflow: on what does the batch_size depend?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I new on tensorflow and I try to understand what size should be `batch`.

Shape of my data `(119396, 12955)`. How can I choose best `batch_size` to my data?
And what dependence `batch_size` from data shape or using algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46654424/6290463

Comment: @ValBerthe not a dup of that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The batch size is the number of input data values that you are introducing at once in the model. It is very important while training, and secondary when testing. For a standard Machine Learning/Deep Learning algorithm, choosing a batch size will have an impact on several aspects:

- The bigger the `batch size`, the more data you will feed at once in a model. Thus, RAM **memory consumption** will be almost **linear with** `batch size`, and there will always be a limit based on your system specs and the size of your model above which your model will overflow.
- The bigger the `batch size`, the **faster** you will **loop over your dataset** N times to perform training.
- A bigger`batch size` will **slow down** your model **training speed**, meaning that it will take longer for your model to get one single update since that update depends on more data.
- A bigger`batch size` will have more data to average towards the next update of the model, hence training should be smoother: **smoother training/test accuracy curves**.

Note that the **size of the data** is only related to the batch size in the sense that the bigger the data, the smaller the maximum `batch size` becomes (limit set by RAM). The **size of the model** also has a similar relation.

In practice, you should follow "in powers of 2 and the larger the better, provided that the batch fits into your (GPU) memory". For more in-depth details, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46655895/9670056.

Comment: great summary @ibarrond