# Is there a torchsummary equivalent in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

I am using GPU to run some very large deep learning models on a dataset of size 55GB. If I use a batch size greater than 1, I get a resource exhausted error. Even with a batch size of 1, I get segmentation faults.

GPU memory is 10GB and Server has 32GB of RAM.

Is there a way that I could know how large the data (batch size of 1) will occupy in the GPU? I am using tf.Keras to fit models. Is there a `torchsummary` equivalent in TensorFlow?

Comment: Sometimes these Deep Learning/GPU errors can be quite opaque. It would be more helpful to show the code/error in case there's something else going on? Maybe you're not setting the batch size correctly or maybe there's another error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate optimal batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654424/how-to-calculate-optimal-batch-size)

Answer (score 0):

In keras (now a part of Tensorflow) you can use `model.summary()` natively. See [here for more info](https://keras.io/api/models/model/#summary-method).

Comment: But `model.summary` does not show how big the batch size is.