# Batch size for Feed-Forward Neural Network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, lstm, feed-forward

I have a 100k dataset for ML, how much should I set up the batch size for training, ?

FYI - I am using the train_test_split library to splitting the data into train and test sets.

Thank you!

## Fit network

> ```
> history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 1500, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, shuffle=False, batch_size=60)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Wannees, You need to give more details so that others can help you. Such as type of data (numeric or image), application, number of features/ targets, network architecture, etc.

You may learn something from the existing question in this web: [How to calculate optimal batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654424/how-to-calculate-optimal-batch-size), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network

Comment: Harry - thank you so much for your responses.  my data are numeric, the number of features is 5 and the target is one.  I am using techniquemany to one.

Comment: Wannees, I suggest to use the batch size in these sets [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]. Can can  try 32 first.

Comment: Will do.  thank you so much, Harry!

Comment: Keep posting, I can follow this topic