# Calculate the maximum batch size

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, out-of-memory, batchsize

Finding the maximum batch size is a cumbersome and often time-consuming process. However, there are some solutions that propose approximate solutions, such as ([How to calculate optimal batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654424/how-to-calculate-optimal-batch-size)). I came up with a method to iteratively find the maximum batch size my GPU can handle without running out of memory.

My current approach involves running a subprocess that calls my training script **experiment.py** with a decreasing batch size until it runs successfully. Finally, it gives me the maximum batch size. If you want to use this method and you have a large dataset where preprocessing would take some time, I would recommend considering a small subset of the dataset and skipping the preprocessing steps. This will ensure that the loop over the multiple runs will run faster. Here is the snippet from **main.py** to be run where I considered 500 as a batch size that would definitely fail:

```
import subprocess

def run_experiment(batch_size):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(["python3", "experiment.py", "--batch_size", str(batch_size)], check=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
        print(f"Batch size {batch_size} succeeded")
        return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        if "CUDA out of memory" in e.stderr:
            print(f"Batch size {batch_size} failed due to CUDA out of memory")
            return False
        else:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e.stderr}")
            return False

def find_max_batch_size(start, step):
    for i in range(start, 0, -step):
        if run_experiment(i):
            return i
    return start

# Run the experiments with different step sizes
batch_size = find_max_batch_size(500, 100)
batch_size = find_max_batch_size(batch_size + 100, 10)
batch_size = find_max_batch_size(batch_size + 10, 1)

print("Maximum batch size : ", batch_size)
```

In **experiment.py**, I've added command line argument parsing for batch size:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, required=True, help="Batch size for the experiment")
args = parser.parse_args()

batch_size = args.batch_size
```

While this works to a degree, it is not very efficient. I'm wondering if there is a more optimal way to dynamically calculate or estimate the maximum batch size a GPU can handle based on its available memory?

Any insights or suggestions?